# Only Printing the First Value of Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have no idea why display function is not displaying anything other than the first node's data. I've tried switching the `While(p!=NULL)` to `while(p->next!= NULL` but when I do that instead of only the first node's data displaying no data is being displayed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int no;
    Node* next;

};


Node* createNode(int no1) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->no = no1;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}


void addValue(int x, Node** head) {
    //insert first node into linked list

    Node* n = createNode(x),*p = *head;

        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = n;
            
        }
        

    //insert second node onwards into linked list
    else {
    
            while (p->next!= NULL) {
                p->next = n;
                p = p->next;

            }

    }
}

void display(Node *head) {
    Node* temp = head;
    // temp is equal to head
    while (temp->next!=NULL) {
        cout << temp->no;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


int main() {
    int num; char choice;

    Node* head = NULL;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a number : ";
        cin >> num;
        addValue(num,&head);
            cout << "Enter [Y] to add another number : ";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'Y');

    cout << "List of existing record : ";
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried changing the contents fo the else while loop in the addRecord function to p = p->next; p->next = n; in that order to no avail.

Comment: Advice -- when making code changes, you need to know *exactly* where and why that code change will correct the problem.  Doing random changes and hoping things work is not the way to go about correcting mistakes in a program.  Before a single line of code is rewritten, you have to have a convincing and compelling reason why that change may correct the problem.  Will the problem be actually corrected?  No, but the prerequisite of knowing why and how you made the change is still required.

Comment: ***I have no idea why display function is not displaying anything other than the first node's data.*** I recommend you get access to a debugger. That way you can create a small 3 to 5 node list in your code and step through your code line by line looking at your variables and flow at each step to see what the code is actually doing instead of guessing. Learning how to debug is an essential skill if you are to ever become a programmer professionally.

Comment: I didn't know debugging was a thing. Will look into it. It'll remove a lot of the guesswork. Thank you!

Comment: The most important things are to set breakpoints, step 1 line and look at the variables. For Visual Studio the most important keys to learn are F9, F10 and F11. Related Visual Studio (Community, Enterprise, Pro) debugging tutorial: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2022](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2022) if you are using gdb or some other IDE I am sure you can find similar documentation. It will probably take about 20 minutes for you to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop, it should be

```
while (p->next!= NULL) {
  p = p->next;
}

p->next = n;
```

Traverse until the end of linked list is reached and then, add the new entry.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I've been inserting a node after traversing every node.

Comment: If it benefits anybody. I also changed the while loop condition from ```while (temp->next!=NULL``` to ``` while(temp!=NULL)``` this ensures all the contents of the list are printed. With the prior condition it wouldn't print the last node contents.

Comment: Since the code is already dealing with a `Node**` pointer-to-pointer (which is the ideal way to deal with linked-list insertions), there is no need to use an `if/else` to single out the processing of the `head` node differently, eg: `void addValue(int x, Node** head) { while (*head) { head = &((*head)->next); } *head = createNode(x); }`